# Cannot see response body in ie8 when response http status code is set to some error code(422)

Tags: internet-explorer, grails

I am making a requset to a web service that sends custom error with proper HTTP header when I notice some validation error, this works fine in chrome and mozilla as things always do and then it broke in ie8 as it always does!
After checking the network activity, I see that ie8 is not able to get response body when HTTP code is other that 200(or at-least it seems so).

In groovy I am returning error like :

```
render(status: 422, contentType: 'TEXT', text: ((errors as JSON) as String))
```

Is there a way I could somehow get ie8 to read in the response body, or as an alternative I might be able to set response header but before trying that I was wondering if you guys have already seen this issue and know a solution to it.

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is weird, I am using ie10 in compatibility mode set to ie8. In groovy I set the code as :

```
render(status: 422, text: (errors as JSON))
```

and it works now. It seems like we need not use contentType in the render. The reason why I was using contentType to begin with - I had set the contentType to JSON(since my response is in JSON) but ie kept on prompting me to download the json response automatically so I did some digging and found that ie8 does that if header is set to application/json, so I changed it to TEXT which took care of the annoying download prompt stuff and I just stuck with it.